# Changing the format of the day title in weekview

Tags: date, view, format, fullcalendar

How can I change the formatting of the date in Fullcalendar -> weekview.
It now says:

```
Sun 7/24  Mon 7/25  Tue 7/26  Wed 7/27 Thu 7/28 Fri 7/29  Sat 7/30
```

I want to switch month and day around so it says

```
Sun 24/7  Mon 25/7  Tue 26/7 Wed 27/7 Thu 28/7 Fri 29/7  Sat 30/7
```

which is the way our users are used to in the country where I live/work.

Answer (score 6):

I have found a solution:

```
columnFormat: {
    month: 'ddd',
    week: 'ddd d/M',
    day: 'dddd d/M'
},
```

Comment: columnFormat with a lower 'c'.

Answer (score 3):

There is a mistake, the first character must be lowercase:

**c**olumnFormat: { month: 'ddd', week: 'ddd d/M', day: 'dddd d/M' },

Answer (score 3):

You can use this undocumented config variable to make a general change for all appearances of date/month so you don't have to specify it per view:

```
dayOfMonthFormat: 'ddd DD/MM',
```

Answer (score 1):

try this then..

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            defaultView: 'basicWeek',
            editable: true,
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 1) // change the format here.
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but my question is about FullCalendar (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/), not the jquery DatePicker.

Comment: my bad.. i've changed my answer.. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with this setting:

```
'ddd'     // like 'Mon', for month view
'ddd M/D' // like 'Mon 9/7', for week views
'dddd'    // like 'Monday', for day views
```

**Example Fullcalendar**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ columnFormat: "ddd D/M" });
```

**OR**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ columnHeaderFormat: "ddd D/M" });
```

For more details Click [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/columnFormat)!