# FullCalendar, how do I change the date format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to make the date format of FullCalendar dd/mm. How can I do this? I found [this][1] method, but I am not really sure how to edit it in my case. I am trying to make it so that in the dayView, the header shows the date in dd/mm format, rather than the current mm/dd American format.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: your link didn't work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this link

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/titleFormat/

You can specify which view you want to edit through this (in your case the day view)

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/View_Option_Hash/

So you would probably have something along the lines of

```
titleFormat: {

day: 'dddd, d MMM, yyyy'   //whatever date format you want here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Sure, you can play with the `titleFormat` [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ELLR/14/)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    titleFormat: {
        month: 'MMMM yyyy',
        week: "MMM d[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;'[ MMM] d yyyy}",
        day: 'MM/dd'
    },
```

Answer (score 6):

As I have written [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872429/jquery-fullcalendar-changing-the-format-of-the-day-title-in-weekview/34919723#34919723) you can use this undocumented config variable to make a general change for all appearances of date/month so you don't have to specify it per view:

```
dayOfMonthFormat: 'ddd DD/MM',
```

Answer (score 1):

Fullcalender has a few utilities functions you can use. You can get at these after the calender has been loaded through the $.fullCalendar.formatDate(, 'dd/mm'). There are also a few others that are work a look.. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/