# How do I change date format in fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, datetime, fullcalendar

I have this function:

**CODE JS:**

```
select: function(start, end, allDay)
            {
                addEditEvent("select",event,start,end);
            },

 function addEditEvent(state,event,start,end)
    {
       if(state=="select")
        { 
           console.log(start._d);  //here display in this format Fri Feb 19 2016 04:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)
        }
    }
```

I want to transform this format in

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

How can I turn this time?
Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FullCalendar, how do I change the date format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491450/fullcalendar-how-do-i-change-the-date-format)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551331/fullcalendar-date-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Use moment for format as fullcalendar use moment library for date.

No need of _d just start

```
select: function(start, end, allDay)
            {
                addEditEvent("select",event,start,end);
            },

 function addEditEvent(state,event,start,end)
    {
       if(state=="select")
        { 
           console.log(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));  
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
titleFormat: {
    day: 'dddd, d MMM, yyyy'   //whatever date format you want here
}
```